# Binarize image "manually"

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to modify an image by looping through the pixels. The code is this

```
    for x in range(image.shape[0]):
        for y in range(image.shape[1]):
            if tuple(image[x, y]) in possible_colors_rgb:
                image[x, y] = [255, 255, 255]
            else:
                image[x, y] = [0, 0, 0]
```

In the array `possible_colors_bg` I have a list of tuples of 3 elements that represent rgb values. The problem is that the if never evaluates as true, even if I am sure that there are some pixels that should satisfy the equality. How can I understand what's wrong?

Comment: Is your image a numpy array?

Comment: I tried it with `image = np.ones((500, 500, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255` and `possible_colors_rgb = [(255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0)]` and the if statement evaluates to true, so it seems like your `possible_colors_rgb` doesn't contain the values that you ant

Comment: Yes, the image is read with cv2.imread that returns a numpy array, and regarding possible_colors_rgb I printed it and it seems to be correct

Answer (score 1):

`cv2` keeps pixel values in BGR order.  If your tuples in `possible_colors_rgb` are in RGB order, they won't match.

```
possible_colors_bgr = [(b,g,r) for r,g,b in possible_colors_rgb]
```

If the number of colors is large you might consider using a `set` instead of a `tuple` or `list` for the possible colors, for better efficiency.